# Feynman diagrams - changing the vertical line

Tags: diagrams, feynman, feynmf, document

I'm trying to draw the Feynman diagrams of the Higgs decay modes:

```
\begin{fmffile}{feyngraph4}
  \begin{fmfgraph*}(120,60)
    %\fmfstraight
    \fmfleft{i1,i3} 
    \fmfright{o1,o2,o3}
    \fmf{gluon}{i1,v1}
    \fmf{gluon}{i3,v3}
    \fmf{fermion}{v1,o1}
    \fmf{fermion}{v3,o3}
    \fmffreeze
    \fmf{fermion,label=,label.side=left}{v3,v2,v1}
    \fmffreeze
    \fmf{dashes}{v2,o2}
    \fmflabel{$g$}{i3}
    \fmflabel{$g$}{i1}
    \fmflabel{H}{o2}
    \fmflabel{t}{o1}
    \fmflabel{t}{o3}
  \end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}
```

how can i put one arrow instead two in the vertical line?

[image]

Comment: Please EDIT your question and complete the code: at the moment it won‘t compile when copied, i.e. you don’t share vital information. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{feynmp}
\usepackage{feynmp-auto}
\begin{document}
\begin{fmffile}{feyngraph4}
  \begin{fmfgraph*}(120,60)
    %\fmfstraight
    \fmfleft{i1,i3} 
    \fmfright{o1,o2,o3}
    \fmf{gluon}{i1,v1}
    \fmf{gluon}{i3,v3}
    \fmf{fermion}{v1,o1}
    \fmf{fermion}{v3,o3}
    \fmffreeze
    \fmf{fermion,label=,label.side=left}{v3,v1}  % <- changed
    \fmffreeze
    \fmfforce{(60,30)}{v2}  % <-- new line (60,30) = 1/2 (120, 60)
    \fmf{dashes}{v2,o2}
    \fmflabel{$g$}{i3}
    \fmflabel{$g$}{i1}
    \fmflabel{H}{o2}
    \fmflabel{t}{o1}
    \fmflabel{t}{o3}
  \end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}
\end{document}
```

Compile this (possibly twice, possibly using `-shell-escape`, etc) to get:

[image]

The auto-layout in `feynmp` is very clever, but I have to admit that I find it quite baffling at times.   Personally, I think that it's much simpler just to learn [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html) and use `feynmp.mp` as a source of macros.   Then you could do this:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
input feynmp
beginfig(1);
    -x1 = -x4 = x3 = x6 = 55; x2 = x5 = 0;;
    y1 = y2 = y3 = -y4 = -y5 = -y6 = 34;
    z7 = 1/2[z3, z6] shifted 7 right;

    draw_gluon z1 .. z2;  draw_fermion z2 .. z3; 
    draw_gluon z4 .. z5;  draw_fermion z5 .. z6; 
    draw_fermion z2 .. z5;
    draw_dashes origin .. z7;

    label.ulft("$g$", z1);
    label.llft("$g$", z4);
    label.urt("$t$", z3);
    label.lrt("$t$", z6);
    label.rt("$H$", z7);
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

which compiles in one single pass with `lualatex` to produce a PDF that looks like this:

[image]

But this approach is not really documented.  You have to read the source code to find out about `draw_gluon` etc...